# Android Media Player: display the words in textview from an array in 1 second interval

Tags: android, textview

**Im trying to display the words from an array in 1 second interval. I have the following codes:**

```
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(tv);

    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nicholas);

    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






    mPlayer.start();
    tv.setText("Playing...");


    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                String words[] = {
                        "Nicholas ",// 0
                        "was ", // 1
                        "older ",// 2
                        "than ",// 3
                        "sin ",// 4
                        "and ",// 5
                        "his ",// 6
                        "beard ",// 7
                        "could ",// 8
                        "go ",// 9
                        "no ",// 10
                        "whiter. "// 11
                };

                int x = 0;
                while(x <= 11) {

                    sleep(1000);
                    tv.append(words[x]);
        x++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

}
```

But when i run it, i got this message: Sorry! The application **** has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

And also, how to display its current playback position.

I'm new to android dev. Many thanks!

Comment: You forgot #enableGaiman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not update UI ( tv.append() ) from non-main thread. 
Please use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to notify main Thread to update it.

EX,

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        tv.append(words[x]);            
    }    
});
```